# In c#, how to link a user control to a form?

Tags: c#, winforms

I created a windows form application, and i have 3 user control windows.
I must have a button that when clicked, it takes the user to its respective User control.

For instance, button (Apply) is on the windows form and shall take the user to Login page (which is a user control).

What is the code for the button for it to take the user to a user control?

I tried the following but did not work:

```
Login l1 = new Login();
l1.Show();
```

Thanks is advance

Comment: Is the Login user control is added to the Form already? Is the button and user control on the same form?

Comment: Check this link: https://andydunkel.net/2019/08/07/open-wpf-windows-from-winforms-application/

Comment: Also check this link https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/465423/opening-wpf-form-from-winforms

Comment: @Sarker How is WPF involved here? There's no reference to this platform.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If is a form you could use:

```
Login l1 = new Login();
l1.Show(this);
```

If is a control, you could use:

```
Login l1 = new Login();
this.Controls.Add(l1);
```